# How to obtain all row numbers that contain certain x/y value combinations in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

lets say a plot select function gives me a data frame of x and y coordinates (values) which we can artificially generate with:

```
newData <- mtcars[ c(1,3,5,9:11) ,c('mpg', 'cyl')]
rownames(newData) <- NULL
colnames(newData) <- c('x', 'y')

    x y
1 21.0 6
2 22.8 4
3 18.7 8
4 22.8 4
5 19.2 6
6 17.8 6
```

How do I find out which rows (i.e. row numbers) in the original `mtcars` contain these x/y value combinations?

I know I can join the two,

```
inner_join(mtcars, newData[ ,c('x', 'y')], by = c("mpg" = "x", "cyl" = 'y'))
```

which gives me a full data frame, but I only need the row numbers

which I need to use inside this:

```
mtcars$selected <- T

mtcars %>%
 (selected = if_else(row_number() %in% '#ANSWER', !selected, selected))
```

in order to switch all selected points from F <-> T

**UPDATE**

I'm running this now:

```
mtcars %>%
    mutate(Selected = if_else(row_number() %in% {mtcars %>% 
            mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
            inner_join(distinct(newData), by = c('mpg' = "x", "cyl" = 'y')) %>% 
            pull(rn)}, !Selected, Selected))
```

In order to pass the column names as variables (such as when coming from a dropdown menu in R Shiny) we can use `setNames(c('x', 'y'), c(xvar, yvar)))`

`xpar <- 'mpg' #(input$xpar_selector in shiny App)`

`ypar <- 'cyl' #(input$ypar_selector in shiny App)`

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(Selected = if_else(row_number() %in% {
      mtcars %>% 
        mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
        inner_join(distinct(newData), by = setNames(c('x', 'y'), c(xvar, yvar))) %>% 
        pull(rn)
       },
        !Selected, Selected))
```

[How to pass column names for inner join by 2 column sets as variables with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56468711/how-to-pass-column-names-for-inner-join-by-2-column-sets-as-variables-with-dplyr/56468740#56468740)

Expected result is:

[image]

Comment: Can we assume that rows in the original data are distinct? Also, do you have control over the select function or do we only have the original df and the selected rows to work from?

Comment: the select is a "drag a square" in a plot. The values are not distinct, i.e. my real data can contain duplicates, and we should collect all matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way -

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  inner_join(distinct(newData), by = c("mpg" = "x", "cyl" = 'y')) %>% 
  pull(rn)

[1]  1  2  3  5  9 10 11
```

Here's how you could insert this in your code -

```
mtcars$selected <- TRUE

mtcars %>%
 mutate(selected = if_else(row_number() %in% {mtcars %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  inner_join(distinct(newData), by = c("mpg" = "x", "cyl" = 'y')) %>% 
  pull(rn)}, !selected, selected))
```

Here's a simpler way of achieving your result -

```
mtcars %>% 
  left_join(
    newData %>% 
      distinct() %>% 
      mutate(selected = FALSE),
    by = c("mpg" = "x", "cyl" = 'y')
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    selected = if_else(is.na(selected), TRUE, selected)
  )
```

However, I am confused as to what you are trying to achieve here.
Maybe you are simply looking for an `anti_join` i.e. get rows from `mtcars` that are not there in `newData` -

```
mtcars %>% 
  anti_join(newData, by = c("mpg" = "x", "cyl" = 'y'))
```

Comment: any idea how to this inside the pipeline I already have at the '#answer" spot? i.e. to flip the selected state of the matching rows and getting the updated full mtcars dataframe as final result?

Comment: I came up with this, not sure if it can be achieved simpler: 
`mtcars1 <- rbind(mtcars, mtcars)
mtcars1 %>%
    mutate(Selected = if_else(row_number() %in% c(mtcars1 %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
                                  inner_join(distinct(newData), by = c("mpg" = "x", "cyl" = 'y')) %>% pull(rn)), !Selected, Selected))`

Comment: yeah i'm purely aiming to flip T/F state in the 'selected column while keeping the whole mtcars table. 
I'm now trying to change it to take the column names from a variable (dropdown input in my shiny app) so: 
`xVar = 'mpg'`
and then 
`mtcars %>%
    mutate(selected = if_else(row_number() %in% {mtcars %>% 
            mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
            inner_join(distinct(newData), by = c(xVar = "x", "cyl" = 'y')) %>% 
            pull(rn)}, !selected, selected))`
but this throw an error for missing column

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option :

```r
library(dplyr,warn.conflicts =  FALSE)
newData %>%
  distinct() %>%
  mutate(match = TRUE) %>%
  left_join(mtcars, by= c(mpg ="x", cyl="y"),.) %>%
  pull(match) %>%
  which()
#> [1]  1  2  3  5  9 10 11
```