# How to pass column names for inner join by 2 column sets as variables with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I've been looking at various suggested approaches for passing a column name as variable such as using bang bang (!!xvar), as.name(xvar) and various others but I can't get it to work.

Does anyone know how to pass the column names used from `mtcars` in the pipeline below as variables?

i.e.

`xvar <- 'mpg'`

`yvar <- 'cyl'`

to build a dummy of my data to do the join with used to determine which rows of Selected to switch  T <-> F

```
newData <- data.frame(trace = 0, point = 1:6, 'x' = unlist(mtcars[ c(1,3,5,9:11) ,1]),  y = unlist(mtcars[ c(1,3,5,9:11) ,c('cyl')]))
rownames(newData) <- NULL

mtcars$Selected <- T

mtcars %>%
  mutate(Selected = if_else(row_number() %in% {mtcars %>% 
      mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
      inner_join(distinct(newData), by = c('mpg' = "x", "cyl" = 'y')) %>% 
      pull(rn)}, !Selected, Selected))
```

but I need to pass `'mpg'` and `'cyl'` as variables: `xpar` and `ypar`
since they are coming from drop down menus in a `Shiny App`

`xpar <- 'mpg' #(input$xpar_selector in shiny App)`

`ypar <- 'cyl' #(input$ypar_selector in shiny App)`

Comment: I get some error in your code `Error in if_else(row_number() %in% { : object 'Selected' not found`  Can you check whether it is working fine

Comment: sorry I forgot the line `mtcars$Selected <- T`. I'll check now if it works

Comment: add  `%>% as.data.table() ` to maintain the data.table class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be to use `setNames`

```
 ...
 inner_join(distinct(newData), by = setNames(c('x', 'y'), c(xvar, var)))
 ...
```

Full code

```
mtcars %>% 
       mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
       inner_join(distinct(newData), by = setNames(c('x', 'y'), c(xvar, yvar))) %>% 
       pull(rn)
#[1]  1  2  3  3  5  9  9 10 11
```

actual full code:

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(Selected = if_else(row_number() %in% {
      mtcars %>% 
        mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
        inner_join(distinct(newData), by = setNames(c('x', 'y'), c(xvar, yvar))) %>% 
        pull(rn)
       },
        !Selected, Selected))
```

Comment: ah cool, I was wrestling with setNames but I was putting the names in the wrong order. I was trying some variations like  c(setNames('x', xVar), setNames('y', 'Concentration'))